# Is there a "branching" string format descriptor?

Tags: c, string-formatting

I just did this

```
printf( (n==0) ? " %d" : " %3d", n );
```

but is there a conditional format descriptor?

So, it would mean something like *"if this is very short use such and such padding, but, if this is longer use such and such padding."*

Can do?

Comment: Another way to do that is `printf("%*d", (n==0) ? 0 : 3, n);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no conditional, but you can use * to specify the width in the arguments. e.g.:

```
printf(" %*d", (n==0)?1:3, n);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the field width as an argument using `*`:

```
printf("%*d", length, n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have pointed out the field width modifier `*`.

Since you're comparing for zero/nonzero to determine the length, you can even hack the value of `n` into a boolean (`1` or `0`), and then multiply that by your desired length:

```
printf("%*d", !!n*3, n);
```

Comment: ...though if you do this in any "real" code base, please write a comment on what and why you are doing this.