# How to printf("%0x") with the number of digits determined from the type?

Tags: c, hex, printf

I can specify the number of digits like `printf("%08x", ...)`. But I'd like to automatically adjust the number of digits according to the data type, (e.g, `long` (64 bits) should automatically have 64/4=16 digits). Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Take a closer look at e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Pay close attention to what `*` means in a format specifier. Also don't forget what `sizeof` returns.

Comment: Even though there is a way: `printf("%0*x", sizeof(n)*2, n);` - it is not clear to me how you can benefit from it. Looks like usable in macros only.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `*` length specifier is certainly usable outside of macros; see the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577653/is-there-a-branching-string-format-descriptor

Comment: @GovindParmar It is, no argument here. The requested usage is questionable.

Comment: You'll need a length modifier as well as controlling the number of digits.

Answer (score 4):

> How to `printf(“%0x”)` with the number of digits determined from the type?

**1) Find the bit width**

Use `sizeof, CHAR_BIT` to find the *bit* width `sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT`<sup>1</sup> or see below alternative.

**2) Find the nibble width**

`(bit_width + 3)/4` for the *nibble* width - number  of hexadecimal characters.

**3) Pass the width**

Use `"*"` to pass in the  *width* and print using the widest type, `uintmax_t`.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTF_XW(x) printf("%0*jx\n", (int)(sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT+3)/4, (uintmax_t) (x))

int main(void) {
  unsigned char uc = 1;
  unsigned short us = 2;
  unsigned u = 3;
  unsigned long ul = 4;
  unsigned long long ull = 5;
  uintmax_t uj = 6;

  PRINTF_XW(uc);
  PRINTF_XW(us);
  PRINTF_XW(u);
  PRINTF_XW(ul);
  PRINTF_XW(ull);
  PRINTF_XW(uj);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output, may differ  amongst platforms.

```
01
0002
00000003
0000000000000004
0000000000000005
0000000000000006
```

---

**Alternative**

Another approach would use `_Generic` - tis a bit more work - and more rewards.
See `unsigned long long uf:42;` example below.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int hexwidth(uintmax_t u) {
  int count = 3;
  while (u) {
    u >>= 1;
    count++;
  }
  return count/4;
}

// Default case useful for other unsigned types wider than `unsigned`
#define HEXWIDTH(s) _Generic((s), \
    unsigned char: hexwidth(UCHAR_MAX), \
    unsigned short: hexwidth(USHRT_MAX), \
    unsigned : hexwidth(UINT_MAX), \
    unsigned long: hexwidth(ULONG_MAX), \
    unsigned long long: hexwidth(ULLONG_MAX), \
    default: hexwidth((s)*0u - 1u) \
    )

#define PRINTF_XW(x) printf("%0*jx\n", HEXWIDTH(x), (uintmax_t) (x))
```

With language extensions that allow wider than `unsigned` fields - works nicely too.

```
int main(void) {
  struct {
      unsigned long long uf:42;
  } s1 = {7};
  struct {
      unsigned long long uf:51;
  } s2 = {8};

  PRINTF_XW(s1.uf);
  PRINTF_XW(s2.uf);
}
```

Output

```
00000000007   <-- 11 digits
0000000000008 <-- 13 digits
```

Macro-magic could replace `hexwidth(uintmax_t u)` as follows with a compile time calculation:

```
#define NW3(x) (((x) > 0xFu) ? 2 : 1)
#define NW4(x) (((x) > 0xFFu) ? NW3((x)>>8)+2 : NW3(x))
#define NW5(x) (((x) > 0xFFFFu) ? NW4((x)>>16)+4 : NW4(x))
#define NW6(x) (((x) > 0xFFFFFFFFu) ? NW5((x)>>32)+8 : NW5(x))
#define NW(x) (((x) > 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu) ? NW6((((x)+0llu)>>32)>>32)+16 : NW6((x)+0llu))

// Default case useful for all unsigned types as wide/wider than `unsigned`
#define HEXWIDTH(s) _Generic((s), \
    unsigned char: NW(UCHAR_MAX), \
    unsigned short: NW(USHRT_MAX), \
    default: NW((s)*0u - 1u) \
    )
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This works well when there is no padding in the type - common amongst standard *unsigned* integer types.

Comment: At least for unsigned types, you can use the ceil of the base-16 log of `(1?-1:expr)` (the max value representable in the unsigned type of `expr`) rather than `sizeof` hacks that assume no padding. For signed types this is harder.

Comment: @R.. The `(1?-1:expr)` has a short-coming: promotes sub-`unsigned` types to `int` returning -1.  Yet is another tool  in the arsenal.

Comment: Indeed. If you don't need to write it in a macro, just write `(T)-1` or `T_MAX` directly, where `T` is the type, known statically. It seems you know this anyway if you have a format string to use with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into C's <inttypes.h>

```
#include <inttypes.h>

unit8_t value = 0x34;
printf("The value formatted for 8 bits is %" PRIx8 ".", value);
```

Note the `PRIx8` is a string, which correctly will format for "printf" "hexadecimal" "eight bits".

Note that the lack of commas between the strings are not a mistake.  This is a formatting technique that uses a feature in C called "automatic string concatenation", such that the three strings will get slapped together.  The `PRIx8` is just a convenience which means the correct formatting for an 8 bit hexadecimal value.

To get the similar output formatted for 32 bits, you would use `PRIx32`.

For a brief overview of the `inttypes.h` output formats, you can look at [Good introduction to <inttypes.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6299323/302139)

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. It's about matching the type, not the style for the max number of digits that might be needed.

Comment: @R.. I think you're focusing on the formatting, but since there is one formatting for every data type in `inttypes.h` there's a formatting to match every type too, as well as a more portable way of representing every type they are likely to use too.

Comment: OP is asking how to automatically select the right number of digits to print.

Comment: I agree with @R.. This does not answer the original question.

Comment: "there's a formatting to match every type too" --> `inttypes.h` has many, yet there are some troublesome holes in C and `printf()`:  `int` _bit-fields_ have implementation sign-ness, so `"%d"` could be technical UB.  Printing `char` numeric value likewise has a similar trouble when `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.  `clock_t, time_t` are most problematic as either might not even be an integer.